# How to install kdesudo in OpenSUSE 12.3

Tags: software-installation, sudo, opensuse, source

I cannot find a way to install kdesudo in OpenSUSE 12.3.

I need to use kdesudo because kdesu (which is pre-installed in OpenSUSE 12.3) is a basic tool which does not obey the sudoers configuration.

I'm happy to build from source if it comes to it, but I can't work out where the authentic source can be safely downloaded for kdesudo.

Comment: Do you mean `kdesu`?

Comment: No, kdesu is already on OpenSUSE 12.3, but it does not work as needed. So I need to install kdesudo and use that instead.

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: I'm following [these instructions](http://pastebin.com/cjA1nQpk) and kdesu is no use because it ignores the fact I've given my user account all-commands access to the steam user account. So I need kdesudo which does obey sudoers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search on [this openSUSE page](https://build.opensuse.org/search) for `kdesudo` and you will get a list of personal repos with it.